# How to change the icons used for printer friendly module

Tags: 7, hooks

I would like to change the icons used in the printer friendly module as the default ones supplied don't suit my theme. How do I go about doing this? I assume I should a hook of some sort, but sure which hook is the appropriate one.

Comment: If the icon is provided by a `background-image` property, you may override the css code

Comment: It is using an img tag to insert the image and not a css tag unfortunately.

Comment: why don't you replace its image by your custom image in the module directory?

Comment: Because that isn't a very good solution since that change would be overwritten the next time the module is updated.

Comment: There are three ways of doing this: 1- replacing image 2- template files which is not your desire 3 - using javascript (in this way you may check the url and change the image if needed).